# Change the cube Data source username and password dynamically in SSAS

Tags: .net, ssis, ssas

I have created and deployed cube in SSAS server with windows authentication.

But every 45 days, As per client request oracle source db password will be changed and stored password information in audit table.

Now, I need to change the password of existing cube which I deployed in server automatically every 45 days. without affecting process.

Please help me.

Comment: What do `.net` and `ssis` have to do with this question?

Comment: is possible to write the script task using SSIS. That was the reason taged SSIS and .Net

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it with SSIS.
Assuming you know the password when starting SSIS package. Create a package, define a connection to your SSAS server with sufficient user rights. Create a String User variable with Password and a String User variable XMLA_Change_Pwd with the following expression:

```
    "<Alter AllowCreate=""true"" ObjectExpansion=""ObjectProperties"" xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine"">
  <Object>
    <DatabaseID>You_SSAS_DB</DatabaseID>
    <DataSourceID>Your_DataSource</DataSourceID>
  </Object>
  <ObjectDefinition>
    <DataSource xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:ddl2=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2"" xmlns:ddl2_2=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2/2"" xmlns:ddl100_100=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2008/engine/100/100"" xmlns:ddl200=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200"" xmlns:ddl200_200=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200/200"" xmlns:ddl300=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300"" xmlns:ddl300_300=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300/300"" xmlns:ddl400=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400"" xmlns:ddl400_400=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400/400"" xsi:type=""RelationalDataSource"">
      <ID>DataSource ID</ID>
      <Name>DataSource Name</Name>
      <Description>Description</Description>
      <ConnectionString>...Put your connection string here...</ConnectionString>
      <ImpersonationInfo>
        <ImpersonationMode>ImpersonateAccount</ImpersonationMode>
        <Account>domain\login</Account>
          <Password>"+@[User::Password]+"</Password>
      </ImpersonationInfo>
      <Timeout>PT10M</Timeout>
      <MaxActiveConnections>120</MaxActiveConnections>
    </DataSource>
  </ObjectDefinition>
</Alter>"
```

Modify this example to match your own Datasource, or better - generate Alter XMLA for DataSource from SSMS and modify it with an expression `+@[User::Password]+` as shown above.
Then add `Analysis Services DDL Task` and specify SourceType - Variable and Source - User::XMLA_Change_Pwd.

Comment: Thanks for your response Ferdipux. I am not changing the ImpersonationInfo, i have to change ConnectionString Parameter (User Id and Password). Is this possible to do same or is thr any metadata tables to do.

Comment: @jay, SSAS does not keep password in a connection string. So, if you are using specific account to access Oracle, you have to use ImpersonationInfo - ImpersonateAccount. Even if you only want to change the Connection String - you have to specify all properties of DataSource. It is due to XMLA design.

Comment: @Ferdipux you can do what is suggested above but put the password on the connection string. Even though this piece of info won't be displayed if you script the data source it will be saved.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, one way to handle this is to add a step to the job that processes your cube.

The step would come before the cube processing step, and it would execute an application (either console or ssis) that would read the audit table to see what the oracle password is currently, and then modify your cube's datasource node to use the current password for the oracle connection.